# Borrow checker error after adding generic parameter to struct

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have code that works, but it stops compiling with a borrow checker error after a change. I don't understand how the change could affect borrow checking.

Common part to both working and non-working code:

```rust
/// Some struct that has references inside
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyValue<'a> {
    number: &'a u32,
}

/// There are many structs similar to `MyValue` and there is a
/// trait common to them all that can create them. In this
/// example I use the `From` trait.
impl<'a> From<&'a u32> for MyValue<'a> {
    fn from(value: &'a u32) -> Self {
        MyValue { number: value }
    }
}

/// `Producer` makes objects that hold references into it. So
/// the produced object must be first dropped before any new
/// one can be made.
trait Producer<'a, T: 'a> {
    fn make(&'a mut self) -> T;
}
```

Here is the working code:

```rust
struct MyProducer {
    number: u32,
}

impl MyProducer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { number: 0 }
    }
}

impl<'a, T: 'a + From<&'a u32>> Producer<'a, T> for MyProducer {
    fn make(&'a mut self) -> T {
        self.number += 1;
        T::from(&self.number)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut producer = MyProducer::new();

    println!(
        "made this: {:?}",
        <MyProducer as Producer<MyValue>>::make(&mut producer)
    );
    println!(
        "made this: {:?}",
        <MyProducer as Producer<MyValue>>::make(&mut producer)
    );
}
```

This compiles and prints the expected output:

```
made this: MyValue { number: 1 }
made this: MyValue { number: 2 }
```

I don't like that `MyProducer` actually implements `Producer` for every `T` as it makes it impossible to call `make` directly on it. I would like to have a type that is a `MyProducer` for a specific `T` (for example for `MyValue`).

To achieve this, I want to add a generic parameter to `MyProducer`. Because the `MyProducer` does not really use the `T`, I use `PhantomData` to prevent the compiler from complaining.

Here is the code after changes:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct MyProducer<'a, T: 'a + From<&'a u32>> {
    number: u32,
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a T>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a + From<&'a u32>> MyProducer<'a, T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            number: 0,
            _phantom: PhantomData::default(),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T: From<&'a u32>> Producer<'a, T> for MyProducer<'a, T> {
    fn make(&'a mut self) -> T {
        self.number += 1;
        T::from(&self.number)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut producer = MyProducer::<MyValue>::new();

    println!("made this: {:?}", producer.make());
    println!("made this: {:?}", producer.make());
}
```

The `main` function now looks exactly as I would like it to look like. But the code does not compile. This is the error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `producer` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:50:33
   |
49 |     println!("made this: {:?}", producer.make());
   |                                 -------- first mutable borrow occurs here
50 |     println!("made this: {:?}", producer.make());
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^
   |                                 |
   |                                 second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                 first borrow later used here
```

I don't understand why it no longer works. The produced object is still dropped before the next one is made.

If I call the `make` function just once, it compiles and works.

I am using edition 2018, so NLL is active.

[Rust Playground: working version before change](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3d8430803a2919fb7dea6aa4ecbb98ef)

[Rust Playground: broken version after change](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=25e9849cd6fa9b87f3ee04a739e184d7)

Comment: why are you borrowing `self` for `'a` in your `make`?  I believe if you are removing that, it would work..  (can't test it atm, I'm on phone..)

Comment: It is there to express that the returned `T` may live only as long as the producer (`self`) that made it. Because it contains reference to the producer. If I remove it, I get `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements`... In both the before and after change versions.

Comment: Because everything is borrowed for that life time throughout the call-chain even when in reality it probably shouldn't.  Once I got home later this afternoon I will give this a go if no one else does.  (In the meantime can you make your snippet [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)?  The _working_ one is fine, but the _not working_ one contains types that are not defined anywhere)

Comment: It is SSCCE. The first code snipped is the common code for both the working and non-working version. Alternatively see the rust playground links at the end.

Comment: Did you have a chance to actually look at the provided answer?

Answer (score 1):

I reduced the *noise* from the code so the following is an even shorter version of the *broken* case which demonstrates the same problem: ([test in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=63bb62974bef1541b30145578951c007))

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyValue<'a>(&'a u32);

impl<'a> From<&'a u32> for MyValue<'a> {
    fn from(value: &'a u32) -> Self {
        MyValue(value)
    }
}

struct MyProducer<'a, T>(u32, PhantomData<&'a T>);

impl<'a, T> MyProducer<'a, T>
where
    T: From<&'a u32>,
{
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self(0, PhantomData)
    }

    fn make(&'a mut self) -> T {
        self.0 += 1;
        T::from(&self.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut producer = MyProducer::<MyValue>::new();
    println!("made this: {:?}", producer.make());
    println!("made this: {:?}", producer.make());
}
```

The main problem here is that the mutable borrow's lifetime is the lifetime of `MyProducer`, that is, the lifetime of the instance called `producer` is the same as the mutable borrow taken in its `make` method.  Because the `producer` instance does not go out of scope (if it would then `MyValue` wouldn't be able to hold a reference to a value stored in it) so the mutable borrow lives until the end of `main`'s scope.  The first rule of borrowing is that there can only be a single mutable borrow of a given value in a scope at any time, hence the compiler error.

If you are looking at my solution here, which is actually working and does what I think you wanted it to: ([test in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0af7a3354d569c0eb78e4c30058a000b)):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyValue<'a>(&'a u32);

impl<'a> From<&'a u32> for MyValue<'a> {
    fn from(value: &'a u32) -> Self {
        MyValue(value)
    }
}

struct MyProducer(u32);

impl MyProducer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self(0)
    }

    fn make<'a, T>(&'a mut self) -> T
    where
        T: From<&'a u32>,
    {
        self.0 += 1;
        T::from(&self.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut producer = MyProducer::new();
    println!("made this: {:?}", producer.make::<MyValue>());
    println!("made this: {:?}", producer.make::<MyValue>());
}
```

then you can see that the mutable borrow only lives as long as the `make` method, therefore after the invocation there's no more living mutable borrow to `producer` in `main`'s scope, thus you can have another one.

Comment: This is similar to the original working code - the user of `MyProducer` must know which type it should make and could even ask for different types on different calls. I want to have the `MyValue` as part of the producer type, i.e. I want to have `MyProducer<MyValue>`. But so far it seems that it requires the `MyValue` to be actually stored in the struct (even with `PhantomData`) and then the lifetimes inside `MyValue` mess up the lifetiime of `MyProducer`...