# Why can't I call a mutating function more than once?

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

This is based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56058392/borrow-checker-error-after-adding-generic-parameter-to-struct).

I have code that is failing with borrow checker error and I reduced it as much as I could. This is the result:

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    s: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    fn foo(&'a mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = MyStruct { s: "aaa" };

    m.foo();
    m.foo();
}
```

It is failing with:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `m` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main-x.rs:13:5
   |
12 |     m.foo();
   |     - first mutable borrow occurs here
13 |     m.foo();
   |     ^
   |     |
   |     second mutable borrow occurs here
   |     first borrow later used here
```

The code was reduced so much that it does nothing useful and could be fixed for example by removing the `'a` lifetime from the `foo` function. But I would like to understand why is the code not ok as it is.

My understanding is that `MyStruct` contains reference to `str` of some lifetime `'a` and `foo` can be called with `self` pointing to `MyStruct` of the same lifetime. I don't see why is `m` considered mutably borrowed after the first call to `foo`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you declare `foo` as

```
 fn foo(&'a mut self) {}
```

you say the mutable borrow of `self` has the same lifetime `'a` as the embedded string. So it stays borrowed as long as the struct lives. Calling `foo` is like definitely giving away the ownership of the struct.

You can fix it by declaring `foo` as

```
 fn foo(&mut self) {}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I understand the compiler's reasoning now, sadly it is not helpful for solving my original issue. I have the reference inside struct inside `PhantomData`. So it is not really held by the struct, I just need to put it there so it can be as a generic argument. But apparently it is all the same to the compiler. I do need the lifetime in `foo`.